# possible to change a script when it is running?

Tags: scripting

Suppose a script has 1000 lines, and the 10 line has a command takes a long time to run and when I find it is running line 10, I find I need to change line 100, is it possible to do that without stop the script first?

We can also stop a process by using command pstop, but I don't know how to let the process to re-read the script and continue to run from where it paused.

Comment: 'script' is a bit vague! Which language?

Comment: I am running a long sql script inside a sql*plus session. Since sql is not a popular language, I think use script language such as bash, or ksh will be easily to understand.

So if the bash script is

do A;
sleep 10000;
do B;

After save it to test.sh, and then run "bash test.sh", and after it completes the "do A", and begin to sleep 10000, I find I need to "do C" instead of "do b" after sleep, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Scripts are usually fully loaded (read) into the memory before execution.